# Retrieve data from the database to table such as comments in the admin control panel

Tags: database, wp-admin, comments, forms, table

Hi guys: I hope that you will be in good health

I use the form below to enter data into the database in WordPress.

```
<form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="mhmd_volunteer_form_submitted">

    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="">
    <input type="email" name="email" value="">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">

</form>
```

and

```
function mhmd_volunteer_form(){

   global $wpdb;
   $name1 = isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ? $_POST['first_name'] : null;
   $name2 = isset( $_POST['last_name'] ) ? $_POST['last_name'] : null;
   $email = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? $_POST['email'] : null;

   $my_table_name=$wpdb->prefix."my_table";

   $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( $my_table_name, array( 'first' => $name1, 'last' => $name2, 'email' => $email) );

}
    add_action( 'admin_post_mhmd_volunteer_form_submitted', 'mhmd_volunteer_form' );
```

My question is: How do I retrieve data in the admin panel as a table, such as comments.
I do not want to add any plugins, and thank you